# Search result paging/sorting bug when sorting by votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When sorting search results by number of votes first item on second page has more votes than last item on first page.

See: 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=15&q=programming
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=15&q=programming&page=2

This returns 15 results per page.
On first page the first question has 2330 votes, last question has 228 votes.
On second page the first question has 1410 votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening due to how we "roll up" to answers in most search cases, however there is a workaround being deployed now that will allow us proper sorting in that roll-up case.

Expect to see this fixed over the weekend (we'll need a re-index pass across all posts on all sites).

*Update:* This is now rolled out across the network, sorting should work as expected now.

Comment: Seems to have re-occurred: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167307/there-seems-to-be-a-sorting-issue-on-votes-tab-view-of-ssis-tag

Comment: Nick, this doesn't seem to have been fixed. [This question with -19 score](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6397/should-we-outright-ban-a-few-tags-when-we-know-they-dont-belong-here), for example, appears on the third page of the highest voted tab with 15 results per page.

Comment: @Asad - Link? I have no idea what search you were running :)  Also note this question is specific to **search results**, which are a completely different system than all other question lists on the site.

Comment: [Here's a link](http://meta.superuser.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=votes) to the first page of the votes tab. Scroll to the bottom, and there's the question with -19 score.

Comment: Is this really a bug, or am I just misunderstanding how the votes tab is supposed to work?

Comment: @Asad that has nothing to do with search, so separate issue (the tag engine we call it)...we're taking a look now as that's definitely a bug, thanks for the report!

Comment: Looks like you fixed it! :D If so, could you please leave an answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168866/different-views-show-different-questions/168867) and/or mark as completed?