# Different views show different questions

Tags: bug, question-lists

Every now and then, I look at questions with a different view than "Active". When I do, it often doesn't show some questions that showed under "Active", or shows questions that weren't shown then.

For example, just before I wrote this, there was a question on MSO that showed up under the Newest Questions tab, was asked 7 minutes ago, but doesn't show up under the Active Questions tab (although it was asked after most of those were modified). (EDIT: It's now under Active as well, suggesting some sort of caching issue).

On MSU, I've noticed a day-old question that appears under Active, but not on the homepage or under Votes (it's at -19, so that might be why it isn't on the homepage, but why isn't it under Votes?).

Why is this?

Comment: What other tab are you comparing to? The homepage?

Comment: @Mysticial Homepage, Active Questions, and Newest Questions can all have differences.

Comment: Obviously, "Newest" and "Active" mean two different things. The homepage only shows a subset of the "Active" questions - biased towards your tags and with some randomization.

Comment: @Mysticial But the newest question should also be active, right? (it was asked after the last activity on the active questions)

Comment: There's probably some caching going on that's causing some small delays. The homepage is heavily cached, so I see delays of up to a minute. But I'm not sure about the question lists.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a question that was asked 7 minutes before yours. The closest one I can find is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168865/200500) that precedes yours by 11 minutes. It is also the second entry in the active tab, so there doesn't seem to be a problem there.

Regarding your second example, the votes tab is sorted in descending order of score, so it isn't surprising you can't find a question with -19 score there.

EDIT:

Your second complaint is pretty legitimate. [This -19 score question](https://meta.superuser.com/q/6397/183377) shows up:

- At the bottom of the [first page](https://meta.superuser.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=votes) of the votes tab with 50 results per page
- At the bottom of the [second page](https://meta.superuser.com/questions?pagesize=30&sort=votes&page=2) of the votes tab with 30 results per page
- At the bottom of the [third page](https://meta.superuser.com/questions?pagesize=15&sort=votes&page=3) of the votes tab with 15 results per page

An earlier [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91113/search-result-paging-sorting-bug-when-sorting-by-votes) on this has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I don't believe the problem has been resolved.

Comment: First part: It now appears, suggesting caching. (however, 7 minutes seems like a long time). Second part: I know it's inverse score order; I checked the _last_ page for it (which is where its score would send it).

Comment: @cpast The question might have been deleted, especially if it was that heavily downvoted. Can you remember the title?

Comment: [Should we outright ban a few tags when we know they don't belong here?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/6397/183377)

Comment: @cpast Ah, gotcha now. This is because of a [long standing bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91113/200500) with the votes tab where low voted questions show up in odd places pagination wise. The question you are mentioning is, oddly enough, at the bottom of the first page in the votes tab.

Comment: You're right; it's on page 3 for some reason.