# Sorting questions by vote is incorrect

Tags: bug

Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?page=1&sort=votes&pagesize=50

It starts off sensible but the last few questions have single digits vote, the last one being 0. The first item on page 2 has 142 votes.

Votes drop off suddenly:
[image]

Note sure if this is tag-specific. The [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?page=1&sort=votes&pagesize=50) tag looks fine (clearly receiving preferential treatment :p), but [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?page=1&sort=votes&pagesize=50) and [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?page=1&sort=votes&pagesize=50) are bugged.

Comment: I had to go to page 3 to find it, but you're right. It also seems to happen on page 11.

Comment: Similar bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168866/200500

Comment: Here's something similar on meta (and links to other similar issues: [Massively downvoted questions are still missing from the list of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142458)

Comment: Temporary cache glitch, it will sort itself out in a short while.

Comment: @Mike yes, but there is indeed a bug causing that glitch. Will bump old report now. [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95408/152859). :)